# Provide "Paste Link" Functionality in C# Winforms App

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard, copy-paste, paste

I would like to add Copy-Paste Link functionality to an application.  The application replaces a complex Excel workbook.  I would like to be able to copy tables, text, and charts from the application and use Paste Link in MS Word.

For the uninitiated:
With Excel, when you use Paste Link for the tables, text, charts, etc. the items update in Word when you change them in Excel.

Does anyone know for sure if this is/is not possible (is it some proprietary feature of MS Word-Excel)?  If not, can anyone point me to some resources that will help (either an app that does this or a tutorial/write-up).

Thanks!

Comment: I would like to do this from a C# app to excel.  I have a client that claims to have seen it, but has no idea how it was done.  I can not find evidence of this anywhere.  It is certainly possible, but whether it is built in to .NET or not is what I question.  If he finds anything I'll let you know.

Comment: I have tried researching this and have covered DDE, OLE, OLE DB, etc.  I think I'm on the right track, and my latest theory is this is done as an OLE DB provider.  But I haven't found much on writing your own OLE DB provider and zilch on this subject in .Net.  This is a personal project, though, so I haven't devoted a ton of time to it.
From the perspective of someone who has to write a lot of reports, I think it's a bit odd that there aren't other apps outside of MS that provides this capability.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to the exact same thing. 
I eventually went for OpenXML sdk 2.0 to add content controls in Word and paste the charts to those spots, like what this blogger does. http://www.dotblogs.com.tw/angus/archive/2010/05/19/15332.aspx

Could you share your code here? I'd really like to learn the OLE DB way. Appreciate it!